# Showing $2\cot^{-1}\left(x^{-1/2}\right)$ and $\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)$ have the same derivative because their difference is constant

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, inverse-function

I'm currently studying calculus and my teacher gave me this challenging problem:

> Show that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same derivative.
>   $$\begin{align}
> f(x) &= 2\cot^{-1}\left(x^{-1/2}\right) \\
> g(x) &= \csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)
> \end{align}$$

Although I do know how to find the derivatives of both and showing that they are equal,

> I was wondering if there was a way to prove this by showing:
>   $$k = f(x) - g(x)$$
>   where k is a constant.

As derivatives do not change if a constant is added to a function, this should make sense.

Upon graphing the two functions, I found that this constant was $\pi/2$. I have tried numerous algebraic methods to find this value but I have failed, I was wondering if anyone could figure out how?

Comment: There might be. You could try to use the fact that $\sin^{-1}(x)=\csc^{-1}(1/x)$, $\cot^{-1}(x)=\tan^{-1}(1/x)$ and that (I'm quoting wikipedia here) $$\sin^{-1}x=2\tan^{-1}\Bigg(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\Bigg).$$ Maybe it'll work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving for $x$ gives ...

$$x = \tan^2\frac{f}{2} = \frac{\sin^2(f/2)}{\cos^2(f/2)} = \frac{1-\cos f}{1+\cos f}$$

$$x = \frac{\csc g+1}{\csc g - 1} = \frac{1+\sin g}{1 - \sin g}$$

Since these are equal, we may conclude
$$\sin g = -\cos f = -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-f\right)=\sin\left(f-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
Thus,
$$g = f-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n \qquad\text{or}\qquad
g = \pi - \left(f - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) + 2 \pi n$$
for some integer $n$. By inspection, you have determined that we can take the first option, with $n=0$. $\square$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.